# Give an example of a system of $n$ linear equations in $n$ unknowns with infinitely many solutions.

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

This exercise below has stumped me and my intuition has always told me that having $n$ unknowns with $n$ linear equations will generally have exactly one solution (when the coefficient matrix is invertible).

> Give an example of a system of $n$ linear equations in $n$ unknowns with infinitely many solutions.

The only other case is when the system has no solutions at all (like two parallel lines). However, I have never heard of a case where you have $n$ equations with $n$ unknowns and end up with an *infinite* number of solutions! I can't even visualize what it would look like. The only time you would have an infinite number of solutions is when you have more unknowns than equations, but this is impossible here.

Comment: As a hint, what happens if your two parallel lines overlap?

Comment: Hint: suppose you have two lines which are the same (this still counts as parallel) - what happens then?

Comment: @ConMan They are clearly the same line. I considered this but just ruled it out because doesn't this just mean that you technically have one equation with two unknowns, instead of *two* equations with two unknowns?

Comment: $x + y = 2, ~2x + 2y = 4.$

Comment: If it bothers you that the equations are the same (or just multiples of each other), then take a more subtle dependence, like $x=y, y=z, x=z$.

Comment: A linear system of $n$ equations in $n$ unknowns $ A x = b $ will have infinite solutions if it has at least one solution, and the coefficient matrix $A$ is not invertible.

Comment: If you want something that isn't obviously just two copies of the same equation, then try going to three equations, and see how you can introduce the same redundancy.

Comment: As other have already mentioned, there are a lot (infinitely many) systems of $n$ equations in $n$ variables which have infinitely many solutions. However, your intuition is right in the sense that all these systems are very similar to systems which have a unique solution (by density of invertible matrices).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $n\geq 2$ variables consider $n-1$ equations in those variables. These will generally have infinitely many solutions because there are more variables then equations.

Now add an $n$-th equation obtained by adding together the previous $n-1$ equations. This $n$-th equation is redundant because every solution of the first $n-1$ will be also a solution of the last one by construction.

Just to make an example in $3$ variables:
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{lcl}
2x-y+z &= &3 \\
x-3y-2z &= &-1 \\
3x-4y-z &= &2
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Answer (score 1):

What about $2x-y=0$ and $4x-2y=0$?

Answer (score 0):

One equation, one unknown:
$$ 0 x = 0 .$$

Comment: This seems to be getting negative votes.  But this answer captures the essence of all the other answers in the simplest way possible.  I honestly think think this is the best answer here.